# Create to do list when a user is created in Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, devise, controller

I'm trying to build a to do list application, where when a user signs up through Devise, a pre-populated to do list is also created at the same time.

I have the standard Devise controllers set up (confirmations, omniauth_callbacks, password, registrations, sessions, and unlocks), as well as a to_do_list controller and a list_item controller. Similarly, I have the User, ToDoList, and ListItem models.

The user would belong to the to do list by default, and the list_items would belong to the to_do_list as well. (Later on, multiple users need to belong to the same to do list.) Where and how would I put the code that creates the one to_do_list and the multiple list_items?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you happen to put this application on GitHub or somewhere? I'm making something similar for my family and am running into issues, would love to see your example!

Comment: Yep. Would you mind if I emailed you the link instead of posting it on here? It's a public repo, but related to my job so I don't want to post it.

Comment: Not at all!  Please do! My email is on my website (don't want to post it here just in case): cassidoo.co

Comment: I sent it. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that would work:

**user.rb**

```
after_create :create_list

def create_list
  @list = ToDoList.create(user_id: self.id)
  # add list items to @list
end
```

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Callbacks/after_create

`after_create()`

Is called after Base.save on new objects that haven’t been saved yet (no record exists). Note that this callback is still wrapped in the transaction around save. For example, if you invoke an external indexer at this point it won’t see the changes in the database.

**Update**

**to_do_list.rb**

```
after_create :create_list

def create_list_items
  # let's say you have an array of list_items
  items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4']
  items.each do |item| 
    ListItem.create(content: item, to_do_list_id: self.id)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. This stores the user_id on the list. Is there a way to generate the list, while storing the list ID on the user? I would have to call User.update within the create_list method, right?

Comment: Depends on what your list includes. If this is a static list of list_items for each user, you can add an `after_create` callback to the  `ToDoList.rb` that will add your list items to the list. See the update .

Answer (score 0):

The create logic (and the rest of CRUD) should be placed in the controller of the view you are using to display the list.

Also I think you may have this backwards, the todo list should belong to the user.  So if you were to locate a list, you could find it through User -> lists